# Relationship between normal subgroups and intersections

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $N_1,N_2\leq G$ normal subgroups of $G$ and $H_1,K_1\leq G$ normal subgroups of $G$ such that $N_1\cap N_2\subseteq K_1\subseteq H_1$.

As the quotients $H_1/N_i$ and $K_1/N_i$ probably make no sense for $i\in\{1,2\}$ ($N_i\not\subseteq K_1$ or $N_i\not\subseteq H_1$), are there subgroups in $G/N_i$ that are isomorphic to or even related with $H_1/K_1$?

The most I can think of is $\bar{H}=H_1N_i/N_i$ and $\bar{K_1}=K_1N_i/N_i$ but $\bar{H_1}/\bar{K_1}\cong H_1N_i/K_1N_i$ which is close, but it's not a quotient in $G/N_i$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you expect that $G/N_i\cong H_1/K_1$,in finite case, $|H_1:K_1|\leq |G:N_i|$ equalit comes only when $G=H_1$ and $K_1=N_i$ ? what do you want to reach?

Comment: I want to find a subgroup in any $G/N_i$ that is, at best isomorphic to $H_1/K_1$ or at least in biyection with $H_1/K_1$.

What I want is to proof that the formation locally defined by the trivial formation $\mathcal{F}(p)$'s with $p$ a prime is indeed a formation.

A formation is a class of groups closed under quotients and with the property that if $G/N_1,G/N_2$ are in the formation, then $G/(N_1\cap N_2)$ is also in the formation.